# Android 4.0.4 TabActivity

Tags: android

I have a app which uses TabActivity and now as the device to upgraded to Ice cream sandwitch, formatting of the tab name is not working. Also images do not show up.

```
   intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StnAircrafts.class);  
   intent.putExtra("EmpID", empid); 
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
   spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Aircraft")
           .setIndicator(Html.fromHtml("<b><H2>Aircraft</H2></b>"), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab2_drawable))                  
           .setContent(intent);    
   tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

How can I fix it for now. Later I will change it to Actionbar and fragment.

Thanks

Comment: why dont you use an inflated layout/view as indicator?

Comment: Because I am creating Tabs dynamically.

Comment: inflating a view is supposed to be done dynamically :)

Comment: oh ok. Can you give me an example. Thanks.